# drawing jack o’ lantern in python

Tags: python, graphics, polygon

Alright guys, I am trying to draw Jack o' lantern, which should include A green stem An orange bodyTwo eyes A nose A mouth
now I know I have to use the following
Circle +Polygon+Rectangle to get it done, here is what I have started

```
def hal():
win = GraphWin("My Circle", 200, 200)
c = Circle(Point(100,100), 50)
c.setFill("Orange")
c.draw(win)
p1 = 50
p2 = 40
p3 = 50
eye= Polygon(p1,p2,p3) ###here is my problem, I could not get it, how can I center
```

it inside the circle so I can make eyes, 
like what are the numbers that I have to use so I 
can put it inside the circle, and how can I figure that, 
so I can know how to do it in the future

```
eye.setFill("Red")
eye.draw(win)
win.getMouse()
```

also for Rectangle, how can I know how to position it at the top of the circle, is there any way I can know that?

Thank you

I am using python 3.3
and this graphic library 
http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Comment: Programming language? Markup language? Graphics library? Generally if you don't tell people which of those you are using they can't help you.

Comment: Python 3.3 and this library http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Comment: Then you may want to tag this question as Python so that it is highlighted to people who favor that tag. I don't know enough Python to help you, but tagging this might get someone else to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got it, its just I had to change the numbers here is the code that has also some description

```
enter code heredef pumpkin():
win = GraphWin("My Circle", 800,600)
c = Circle(Point(400,400),200)
c.setFill("Orange")
c.draw(win)
eye= Polygon(Point(500,270), Point(430,400), Point(550,400))
eye.setOutline("yellow")
eye.setFill("Red")
eye.draw(win)  #lesgoleft,#les=up,lessgoleft
reye= Polygon(Point(250,280), Point(230,400), Point(350,400))
reye.setOutline("yellow")
reye.setFill("Red")
reye.draw(win)#moreright
moth=Polygon(Point(250,500), Point(450,540), Point(370,500))
moth.setOutline("yellow")
moth.setFill("Red")
moth.draw(win)                             #moregoright
nose=Polygon(Point(380,400), Point(340,480), Point(500,480))
nose.setOutline("yellow")
nose.setFill("Red")
nose.draw(win)
up= Rectangle(Point(360,200),Point(430,100))
up.setFill("dark green")
up.draw(win)
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```